# gcloud pubsub publish message issue

Tags: gcloud, publish-subscribe

```
I am trying to publish the message on topic but I am not able to publish the message. I am using laravelframework. My subscription is push type.
```

I have used *$ composer require google/cloud-pubsub* from  https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-pubsub link
I have followed this link: (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#php)

```
**use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;**
function publish_message($projectId, $topicName, $message)
{
    $pubsub = new PubSubClient([\[][1]
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $topic = $pubsub->topic($topicName);
    $topic->publish(['data' => $message]);
    print('Message published' . PHP_EOL);
}

I am getting this error (open this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXHZ5.png.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXHZ5.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question would benefit from a more detailed explanation.

As it is, the code you show is the same code as published by Google.

Assuming (!?) Google's code works (probable but not certain), your code should work.

Since we know your code doesn't work, it's probably something else.

I suspect you've missed one or more of the following possibly the last steps:

- created a Google Cloud Platform project (`$projectId`)?
- enabled the Pub/Sub API?
- created a Pub/Sub topic [and >=1 subscriber] (`$topicName`)?
- created (service account) credentials permitted to publish to this topic?
- set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to the account's key?

How are you running the code?

If possible please also `print` the `ClientException` that you show in the image.

#### Update

I tested Google's code and it works for me:

```sh
BILLING_ID=[[YOUR-BILLING]]
PROJECT_ID=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
TOPIC_NAME=[[YOUR-TOPIC-NAME]]

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}


# Enabled Pub/Sub and create topic=subscription=${TOPIC_NAME}

gcloud services enable pubsub.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud pubsub topics create ${TOPIC_NAME} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud pubsub subscriptions create ${TOPIC_NAME} \
--topic=${TOPIC_NAME} \
--project=${PROJECT}


# Create service account ${ROBOT} and key `./${ROBOT}.json`
# Grant the account `publisher` permissions

ROBOT=[[YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME]]

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ROBOT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./${ROBOT}.json \
--iam-account=${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/pubsub.publisher
```

Then -- and apologies, I'm no PHP developer -- here's what I did:

`composer.json`:

```
{ "require": { "google/cloud-pubsub": "1.24.1" } }
```

`pubsub.php`:

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;

// Expects Env PROJECT_ID, TOPIC_NAME **and** GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
$projectId = getenv("PROJECT_ID");
$topicName = getenv("TOPIC_NAME");

$pubsub = new PubSubClient([
        "projectId" => $projectId
]);

$topic = $pubsub->topic($topicName);
$topic->publish(["data"=>"Hello Freddie!"]);
print("Message published" . PHP_EOL);

?>
```

Then:

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./${ROBOT}.json
export PROJECT_ID
export TOPIC_NAME
php pubsub.php
```

> **NOTE** the code implicitly assumes `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to authenticate against the service, see [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable)

yields:

```
Message published
```

And:

```sh
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull ${TOPIC_NAME} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(message.data)"
Hello Freddie!
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the issue you are faced is because of you must have missed the authentication step. Have you created a SA and downloaded the json file to authenticate? If so, double check that you have this line in your filesystem:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account-credentials.json
```

Comment: I have used follow code to test whether GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is working or not. Its working. I got the bucket list. It means its authenticating.

$projectId = getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT');
$serviceAccountPath = getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');

  
$config = [
    'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
    'projectId' => $projectId,
];
$storage = new StorageClient($config);

# Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
    echo "<br>";
    printf('Bucket: '. $bucket->name());
    echo "<br>";
}

Comment: Ok, it seems like you have access to buckets, but have your checked if the SA has the appropriate permissions to publish  on a topic? As you can see here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control, the minimum permission needed is the projects.topics.publish o maybe the roles/pubsub.publisher role.

Comment: going through Cloud I AM page, I can see I have given admin access for Pub/Sub. but when I tried to use following code to check the permission, I am getting error. What could be the issue here?